# Sybase 15.7 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

Tags: linux, datasource, sybase, rhel

I am migrating to Red Hat from Solaris.  Previously on Solaris, we connected to Sybase datasources through Java by passing an interfaces file location to a JDBC library.  When I checked the Sybase documentation, they only list interfaces files as an option for UNIX and Windows...  Does anyone know what the equivalent is for Linux?

I know our datasources have been transfered over, because when i connect with:

```
isql -S <server> -U <user> -P <password>
```

I can connect to the database.  Unfortunately the team who installed the software on our new machines is unable to provide any details...

In summary, I know our datasource profiles are listed somewhere, because I can specify a server by name and connect.  I need to find out where that information is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interfaces file on Linux works the same as on Unix.  It should be in the root of the Sybase ASE installation.

Assuming you have the Sybase ASE environment sourced in your shell it should be:

```
$SYBASE/interfaces
```

The utilities to edit the file are `dscp` or `dsedit,`.
To run `dsedit`:

```
$SYBASE/$SYBASE_OCS/bin/dsedit
```

To run `dscp`:

```
$SYBASE/$SYBASE_OCS/bin/dscp
```

Comment: Thanks Michael,  I ended up using dscp instead of dsedit, i found some useful documentation here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35831.1570/html/uxconfig/X38406.htm

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.