# where can I find Sybase Interface file in Linux system?

Tags: interface, sybase

I am getting the following error while running my c - code which tries to establish a connection using dbopen().
error code:20012  Server name not found in interface file 
I am not able to find the interface file yet. I would appreciate if anyone can share thoughts on this please.

Comment: My answer here should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734208/sybase-15-7-on-red-hatenterprise-linux-server-release-6-4-santiago/21735610#21735610

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sybase 15.7 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734208/sybase-15-7-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-server-release-6-4-santiago)